# Substring in string array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, substring

I have a problem with arrays of strings.

```
public string[] Begin;    
....
for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(Areas); i++)
{
    Begin[i] = text.Substring(j, 4);
}
```

It gives an System.NullReferenceException error.

But it works fine without an array:

```
public string Begin;    
....
for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(Areas); i++)
{
    Begin = text.Substring(j, 4);
}
```

I just can't understand what is the difference and how can I fix it?

Comment: Has Begin been initialized with any strings? If it has that part of the code isn't represented in what you have above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`. And please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: _"what is the difference"_ - `Begin[i] =` versus `Begin =`. See duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. Tried to find themes like my, but without result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you never initialized `Begin` array so is null. You need to instantiate it before being able to assign something to it.

You could initialize your array like this

```
Begin = new string[Int32.Parse(Areas)];
```

Difference between `string[]` and `string` is quite big. First is an array of strings that may hold one or more string instances. Second is a single string.